# Отправка почты в Yii2 какая то ошибка аунтификации

Tags: yii2

немогу понять что за ошибка, при отправки почты выдает Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "rpk54@yandex.ru" using 3 possible authenticators

если отправляю в файл то все ок(тестовое)

отправляю с локального хоста

код

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.yandex.ru',
                'username' => 'rpk54@yandex.ru',
                'password' => 'пароль',
                'port' => '465',
                'encryption' => 'ssl'
            ]
        ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел проблему

Яндекс не принимает обычный пароль от почты для сторонних приложений.
Необходимо создать отдельный пароль для приложения.
Зайти в web-интерфейс. Настройки->Безопасность->Включите и создайте пароли приложений.